# Watching the animation or viewing the animation

Tags: verbs

I know in the case of movies or TV "*watching*" is used, but I have consulted some animation tutorials and in the description they usually write "*viewing the animation*", which is the right one for this case?

[image: viewing]

[Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest "view" in this case is verb definition 15 from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/view?s=t):

> to look at; survey; inspect

When you "view your animation" within a piece of animation software, you're inspecting it to see how it looks, to make sure it looks how you want it to.

When you're happy with it, create a final version, and sit down with friends later: that's when you *watch* it.

Comment: Clear, concrete and practical, exact what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that some words take on new meanings in different contexts, especially in areas such as *computing*, from which your example is drawn, because it has its own set of *terminology*. While most terminology is rooted in the original linguistic meanings of words they can mean something quite different.

From a purely linguistic point of view (no pun intended) the words "watch" and "view" have slightly different meanings. "Watch" suggests looking at something for a sustained length of time - for example you don't "watch" a photograph. Well, you could, but it wouldn't do much. But when speaking about TV for example the two words are pretty much interchangeable. Most people speak of "*watching*" television, but those who work in TV usually refer to their audience as "*viewers*", not "watchers"!

However, in many software applications the term "view" is used to describe a particular screen configuration. For example in Microsoft Word you have a *view* menu where you can choose to look at your work in *Print Layout*, *Web Layout*, *Full Screen* etc. As the screen configuration is called "a view" it is only natural that you would talk about "viewing" it.

Similarly, your example seems to be drawn from the documentation of a software package. It even refers to "*the Animation view*" which is the *name* of a view (note 'Animation' is capitalised). So it makes sense that it would speak of "*viewing*" animations this way. If this is an animation package for creating animated sequences, I am fairly confident that once you had exported the finished product and placed it on some common medium such as YouTube for example, people would talk about *watching* it.

Answer (score -1):

According to [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org) following are the verbal meanings of the words;

1. [Watch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/watch)

   - LOOK AT (eg: You can watch the trains going by from this window.)
   - BE CAREFUL (eg: You need to watch him - he's a strange character.)
2. [View](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/view)

   - HAVE OPINION (eg: We view future developments with some trepidation.)
   - SEE (eg: You can view the sharks from outside the glass tank.)

"viewing the animation" implies *watching the animation then having an opinion over it.*

Comment: These are correct dictionary definitions but they don't fit the given context.